# How to get sum of quantity of products from a specific date?

Tags: mysql

TABLE 1 Sales

```
id   |  date
=================
1    |  10 july
2    |  10 july
3    |  20 july
```

TABLE 2 Products

```
sale_id   |  product_name | quantity
====================================
1         | cold drink    | 2
1         | Samosa        | 3
1         | Burger        | 1
2         | Burger        | 4
3         | Shwarma       | 1
```

I want to get product name and their quantity sold on a specific date
for example
on july 10 there two sales with id 1,2 and product sold on that date are

```
cold drink  2
samosa      3
Burger      5 (1 sold in sale 1 and 4 sold in sale 2)
```

How do i do that in mysql?

i have tried using 
`Select product_name, SUM(quantity) From Products GROUP BY product_name`
but this query give me all the sum i want sum from a specific date , how do i relate these two tables.

Comment: if only there were some way to `JOIN` those two tables...

Comment: ain't that a brain teaser? :D

Comment: `Select product_name, SUM(quantity), date From Products LEFT JOIN Sales ON Sales.id = Products.sale_id GROUP BY product_name, date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data for all days then use this

```
SELECT products.product_name, sales.date, sum(products.quantity) 
FROM products LEFT JOIN sales 
ON products.sale_id = sales.id group by products.product_name, sales.date;
```

If you want the data on date specific the you can use this:

```
SELECT products.product_name, sales.date, sum(products.quantity) 
FROM products LEFT JOIN sales 
ON products.sale_id = sales.id WHERE sales.date = '10 july' group by products.product_name, sales.date;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2joXefi9TLnnf2qf5QqPhL/0)

Comment: Hey man what about range of e.g. i want data from 10-20 july ?

Comment: @TauseefAhmad What is the datatype of the date field? If it is date type then just use between or >= and <= in where condition with sales date like.. sales.date >= '2019-07-10' and sales.date <= '2019-07-20'. If you're storing the date as varchar or string then you need to convert it to date and then you will run the query.. Provide the datatype of the field and exact value's you're storing.. like i didn't see year in your question so.. is year in there or not? After that only i will give you exact query for this

Comment: Actually it's datetime

Comment: I used date >= fromdate and <= to-date didn't work what it does is what it does is displays the count for separate dates separately

Comment: Yes.. it will display it in separate date as you're grouping it with date..  if you want it only based on product then remove the date from select and group.. that will solve this..

Comment: Thanks, man that works. Just one more thing how do I sort it ascending or descending?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least two solutions for this.

1. You can use subselect:

   ```
   SELECT
     product_name,
     SUM(quantity) sum, 
     date
   FROM Products 
     JOIN (
       SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE date = '2019-07-10'
     ) s ON s.id = Products.sale_id
   GROUP BY product_name, date
   ORDER BY sum;
   ```

   Result on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aedf8/2).
2. You can use HAVING for date matching:

   ```
   SELECT
     product_name,
     SUM(quantity) sum, 
     date
   FROM Products 
     JOIN Sales ON id = sale_id
   GROUP BY product_name, date
   HAVING date = '2019-07-10'
   ORDER BY sum;
   ```

   Result on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aedf8/6).