# how to reorder table rows based on a column?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So i have table being echoed using php. i take data from the database and i populate the table. now i have data coming not in order. so my table is not in order. here is the table like

```
product | quantity | amount
===========================
Samosa  |   2      | 20
Shwarma |   1      | 50
Fries   |   1      | 30
```

i want to reorder the table using any method javascript,jquery,php.
i want the amount to be in descending order like this

```
product | quantity | amount
===========================
Shwarma |   1      | 50
Fries   |   1      | 30
Samosa  |   2      | 20
```

things to note that 1) i calculate the amount after i fetch the data so i can't order it using mysql `ORDER BY` 2) i fetch and populate the data using an ajax request.

how do i do that?

Comment: _i calculate the amount after i fetch the data so i can't order it using mysql ..._ Why is that? Isn't it simpler to let mysql do the job?

Comment: coz i have product prices in different table and quantity sold in different table

Comment: _coz i have product prices in different table and quantity sold in different table..._ That is just how itt should be properly. This is not the reason!

Comment: Although I completely agree with B001ᛦ, you could have a look at [DataTables](https://datatables.net).

Comment: i know but it's complicated :D

Comment: Use a `JOIN` to combine data from the 2 tables, and do an `ORDER BY` on that. Its not very difficult.

Comment: im already joining two tables to get product sold information on a specific date, should i add a 3rd one in it

Comment: @TauseefAhmad Yes you can join more than 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function worked for me.

```
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      // Check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated solution for a trivial problem.

Comment: Post an answer explaining how should I do it. I will accept it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151194/how-to-get-sum-of-quantity-of-products-from-a-specific-date/57151846?noredirect=1#comment100872296_57151846

Comment: The question above contains information of two tables. The third table contains product names and price of each product. How can I get amount and quantity in a single query and sort the amount descending.

Comment: Search for how to join 3 tables, you will get the answer fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP using uasort:

```
uasort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['quantity '] > $b['quantity '];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May below code is work for you. As per your requirement I am code some line.

```
$myData = array(
    array(
        'product' => 'Samosa',
        'quantity' => '2',
        'amount' => '20',
    ),
    array(
        'product' => 'Shwarma',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'amount' => '50',
    ),
    array(
        'product' => 'Fries',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'amount' => '30',
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myData);
uasort($myData, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['amount'] < $b['amount'];
});

print_r($myData);
die;
```

output of code is

input

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Samosa
            [quantity] => 2
            [amount] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => Shwarma
            [quantity] => 1
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => Fries
            [quantity] => 1
            [amount] => 30
        )

)
```

result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Shwarma
            [quantity] => 1
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => Fries
            [quantity] => 1
            [amount] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => Samosa
            [quantity] => 2
            [amount] => 20
        )

)
```